# Why index seek and not a scan for the following setup in SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have created a table

```
create table #temp(a int, b int, c int)
```

I have 2 indexes on this table:

1. Non clustered non unique index on c
2. Clustered Index on a

When I try to execute the following query:

```
select b from #temp where c = 3
```

I see that the system goes for index scan. This is fine, because the non clustered index doesn't have b as the key value. Hence it does an index scan from column a.

But when I try to execute the below query:-

```
select b from #temp where c= 3 and a = 3
```

I see that the execute plan has got only index seek. No scan. Why is that?

Neither the clustered index nor the nonclustered index as b as one of the columns?

I was hoping an index scan.

Please clarify

Comment: Why were you hoping for and index scan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `a` as your clustering key, then that column is included in all non-clustered indices on that table.

So your index on `c` also includes `a`, so the condition

```
where c= 3 and a = 3
```

can be found in that index using an index seek. Most likely, the query optimizer decided that doing a index seek to find `a` and `c` and a key lookup to get the rest of the data is faster/more efficient here than using an index scan.

BTW: why did you expect / prefer an index scan over an index seek? The index seek typically is faster and uses a lot less resources - I would always strive to get index seeks over scans.

Comment: +1.  Spot on. I think poster was asking why it can seek rather than they want a scan (which is how I originally interpreted the question)

Comment: +1 Just to add a couple of points. (1) For a non unique non clustered index the CI key gets added to the NCI key rather than as an included column. (2) Presumably the additional selectivity implied by the additional condition makes it prefer the seek as fewer lookups.

Answer (score 0):

> *This is fine, because the non clustered index doesn't have b as the key value. Hence it does an index scan from column a.*

This assumption is not right. index seek and scan has to deal with WHERE clause and not the select clause.

Now your question -

Where clause is optimised by sql optimizer and as there is a=3 condition, clustered index can be applied.